# $x=x^2$ in a sub group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I have a set `E` defined in ℝXℝ (`E=ℝXℝ`) and the operation `*`
defined like this

```
(a,b)*(c,d)=(a+c,b+d+2ac)
```

`(a,b),(c,d)` are elements of `E`, I want to

- prove that `(E,*)` is a [Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)).
- prove that the set `H` defined like so `H={(x,x), x ∈ ℝ}` is a [Sub Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) of `(E,*)`.
- we define the function `f` like so :

  ```
     f: (ℝ, + )→ (H, * )                    
         x     → f(x)=(x,x²)
  ```

  prove that f is a Group homomorphism.

-To prove that E is Group, I must prove its **Closure** that's mean 
For all `(a, b), (c,d)` in `E`, the result of the operation, `(a,b) * (c,d)`, is also in `E` (verified).

**Associativity**
For all `(a,b), (c,d)` and `(e,f)` in `E`

```
 ((a,b) * (c,d)) * (e,f) = (a,b) * ((c,d) * (e,f)).
```

and that's mean :

```
((a,b)*(c,d))*(e,f)=(a+c,b+d+2ac)*(e,f)=(a+c+e,b+d+2ac + f + 2(a+c)e) 
==
(a,b)*((c,d)*(e,f))=(a,b)*(c+e,d+f+2ce)=(a+c+e,b + d+f+2ce + 2(c+e)a)
```

(verified)

**Identity element**
There exists an element `(e1,e2)` in `E`, such that for every element `(a,b)` in `E`, the equation `(e1,e2) * (a,b) = (a,b) * (e1,e2) = (a,b)` holds.
if we develop we get  :

```
{a+e1==a     => e1=0
{b+e2+2ae1=b    =>e2=0 (using e1=0)
```

so `(e1,e2)=(0,0)`

**Inverse element:**
let `(a1,b1)` be the Inverse element of `(a,b)`

```
(a1,b1)*(a,b)=(a,b)*(a1,b1)=(0,0)
{ a1+a=0 =>a1=-a
{ b1+b+2a1a=0 =>b1=2a²-b
```

so the inverse element of `(a,b) is (-a,2a²-b)`

**The Problem**

now the problem occurred when i tried to prove that `(H, * )` is a Sub Group of `(E, * )` because to do that you must prove that whatever element `(a,a)` in `H`, its Inverse element `(a',a')` must also be in `H`, but as you can see that the Inverse element of `(a,a)` is `(-a, 2a²-a)` which is clearly not an element of `H`    ?

And if you take a look at the Question 3 you can see that `f(x)=(x,x²)` is supposed to be an element of `H` (`f` goes from `E → H` )! and that's mean that `x²=x` !!

I exclude the possibility that the question it self is Wrong, am i missing something here ?
..any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: thx..... i will edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $H=\{(x,x)\}$ isn't closed under the group operation:$(s,s)*(t,t)=(s+t,2st+s+t).$
However if we reset $H$ to be the pairs $(x,x^2)$ it is closed, i.e. with this reset the group operation gives $(s,s^2)*(t,t^2)=(s+t,(s+t)^2).$ So if you work with this other definition of $H$ you can likely find the inverses also.

Note that from the third part of the question, about a homomorphism from $R$ to $H$ given by $f(x)=(x,x^2)$ it would seem the question setup was for the $H$ to consist of pairs $(x,x^2)$.

Comment: @anorton You missed that I used the same operation from $(E,*)$ in computing $(s,s^2)*(t,t^2),$ so it is indeed a subgroup.

Comment: this was in a Math university exam, the question was "verify that (H,* ) is a Sub Group of (E,* )", not whether it is or not!, does that mean that they made a mistake ??

Comment: Yes a mistake, or perhaps a typo, especially given the last comment I just added about what the question asks about a homomorphism into $H$... (Are you *certain* there wasn't a square on the second coordinate in the $H$ definition in the given exam paper?)

Comment: okay thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This just addresses the question of showing that your formulas give you a group. It may well be that you don’t yet have the background for getting this on your own, but it does represent a much quicker route to the desired result.

One would be awfully surprised if this proposed group structure could not be represented as matrices. Indeed, after just a little experimentation, I saw that you could represent $(a,b)$ as the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&a&b\\0&1&2a\\0&0&1}\,.
$$
You multiply two,
$$
\pmatrix{1&a&b\\0&1&2a\\0&0&1}\pmatrix{1&c&d\\0&1&2c\\0&0&1}
=
\pmatrix{1&a+c&b+d+2ac\\0&1&2(a+c)\\0&0&1}\;
$$
just what you wanted it to be. Finally, you calculate the inverse of the matrix with $a$ and $b$ in the first row, and find that it is of the right form, and its first row entries are $-a$ and $-b+2a^2$. You have a group because your special matrices form a subgroup of the group of matrices of determinant $1$, done.